# Given $\cos A$ and $\cos B$ , find $\cos C$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> In a triangle $ABC$, $\cos A = 3/5$ and $\cos B = 24/25$. Find the value of $\cos C$.

Question: Is this even possible since cosine is adjacent over hypotenuse?
Or is there a formula or theorem involving these kind of problems?

Comment: Use that cosine has an inverse (arccos) and that the angles of a triangle add to $180^\circ$ (or $\pi$ radians if you prefer).

Comment: $\cos(\pi -A-B) =?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a triangle $A+B+C=\pi$, hence
$$\cos(C)=\cos(\pi-(A+B))=-\cos(A+B)=\sin(A)\sin(B)-\cos(A)\cos(B)$$
where $\cos(A)=\frac{3}{5}$ implies $\sin(A)=\frac{4}{5}$ and $\cos(B)=\frac{24}{25}$ implies $\sin(B)=\frac{7}{25}$. It follows that
$$ \cos(C) = \frac{4\cdot 7-3\cdot 24 }{5\cdot 25}=\color{red}{-\frac{44}{125}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$A+B+C = \pi \implies C  = \pi -(A+B) \implies \cos(C) = -\cos(A+B)$$

Answer (score 1):

it is $$-\cos\left(180^{\circ}-(A+B)\right)=-\cos(A+B)=-\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)$$

Comment: $\color{red}-\cos(A+B)$.

Answer (score 0):

From $\cos A$ and $\cos B$ we know angles A and B by $\arccos$ and use $A+B+C=180°$ or as alternative note that from the latter we can use trigonometric identities to find out $\cos C$.

Notably with the forst method we obtain

$$\cos C=\cos \left(\pi - \arccos \frac35 - \arccos \frac{24}{25}\right)=-\frac{44}{125}$$

For the second, as an alternative to the standard way shown in other answers, for example we can use [the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Further_formulas_for_the_case_%CE%B1_+_%CE%B2_+_%CE%B3_=_180%C2%B0)

$$\cos ^{2}A +\cos ^{2}B +\cos ^{2}C =-2 \cos A \cos B \cos C +1 \\\implies\cos^2 C+\frac{144}{125}\cos C+\frac{176}{625}=0 \implies \cos C=-\frac{44}{125}$$